# Don´t see error messages when build project

Tags: c#, msbuild, msbuild-task

My problem is that when I start the build, or rebuild do not show me the messages in the output window or in the error window. I tried LogError, LogWarnings and LogMessage.

```
 public override bool Execute()
    {
        Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, "*****************");
        Log.LogWarning("*****************");
        Log.LogError("*****************");

        try
        {
            this.Load(this.Input, this.Output);
            this.Parse(this.ParentElement, this.Element);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            base.Log.LogError(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I also tried to set up different statements in the Build and Run (normal, detailed ...). I use Visual Studio 2013

Comment: In VS's **Output** window pane, ensure **Show output from** is set to _Build_. I know sometimes things can change it (I'm looking at you Ankh)

Answer (score 1):

go to **tools>> Options**

under **debugging>> output window**

make sure you have following settings:

[image]

**NOTE**: This settings i have in *VS2010*. in 2013 there would be similar settings.

Comment: Yes. I have this all set up and it does not work. There is not error, I have everything "on"